# Using yield return to return objects that inherit form a base type

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I have a bas class called `Media` with two classes that inherit from it, `Photo` and `Video`. I am trying to create a collection for the media base class to hold those photo and video objects. So I have created a `MediaList` class as follows:

```
public class MediaList: ICollection<Media>
{
    private readonly XElement _mediaElement;

    public MediaList(XElement mediaElement)
    {
        _mediaElement = mediaElement;            
    }

    public IEnumerator<Media> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (XElement element in _mediaElement.Elements())
        {
            Media media;
            switch (element.Name.LocalName)
            {
                case "video":
                    media = new Video(element);
                    break;
                case "photo":
                    media = new Photo(element);
                    break;
                default:
                    media = null;
                    break;
            }
            yield return media;
        }
    }

    //Rest of ICollection Implementation
}
```

When I iterate the list I get the following exception:

The value "Tool.Photo" is not of type "Tool.Video" and cannot be used in this generic collection.

If I am returning a `Media` object, why is it throwing the exception? Is there a better way to get around this?

Comment: No Media is not Abstract

Comment: You sure the code is exactly as is? Can you show the client code - mesuspects a (co/contra)variance in the client code.

Comment: Glad you found your answer, but check out mine.  There are some style issues with your code, the most important of which is returning a null from an iterator.

Comment: You need to show the line where you get that error, as well as the definition of Media, Photo and Video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is elsewhere. What you have written is fine, as long as both Video and Photo inherit from Media. Maybe you are trying to cast it incorrectly somewhere else.

Comment: After digging around, you are right, my problem is elsewhere. The questions is where? Sigh back to stepping through code :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var array = new string[] { "video", "photo", "hurf", "photo" };
        var ml = new MediaList(array);
        foreach(var element in ml)
            Console.WriteLine(element.GetType().Name);
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class Media { }
public class Video : Media { }
public class Photo : Media { }

public class MediaList
{
    private string[] elements;
    public MediaList(string[] elements) { this.elements = elements; }
    public IEnumerator<Media> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (string s in elements)
            switch (s)
            {
                case "video":
                    yield return new Video();
                    break;
                case "photo":
                    yield return new Photo();
                    break;
            }
    }
}
```

You can slap this into a console app to test it.

Notice a couple different things.  **First**, you never yield return a null.  That doesn't have anything to do with your issue, but nobody expects an enumerable to return a null and will cause you problems later on.  **Second**, I'm not casting what I return.  All casting is implicit or handled by the compiler, so there isn't any need for me to do this.  **Third**, this compiles and works, as does your original code.  Your issue is happening somewhere else, as you will find if you drop this code into a console app and test it.

Comment: +1 That is the exact code that I had in the beginning until I went down the wrong rabbit whole :-)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the method with  the yield return be typed to return `IEnumerable<Media>`,  not `IEnumerator<Media>` ?

But more basically, this pattern leaves me with a bad smell.  Every time you use foreach on this "collection", you will be creating (instantiating) new instances of each `Photo` or `Video` object in the `_mediaElement.Elements()` list. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Isn't the yield return returning Media objects?  (not an Enumerator of Media objects.)

Comment: An Enumerator is state-maintenance object created when calling foreach to keep track of which object in the collection is the current one, and increment that state to the next one each time foreach iterates.  When using yield return, an enumerator is created for you by the c# compiler.

Comment: Under normal circumstances I would agree with you, but in this case the media objects are just fly weights and the collections is only iterated through once.

Comment: Perhaps I am not clear, but doesn't the GetEnumerator() methods' return type (which you have as IEnumerator<Media>) STILL need to be the return type required by yield return (which is IEnumerable<>)? I mean if the method is to return IEnumerator<>, where in GetEnumerator() is an object which implements IEnumerator being constructed ??  Your yield return returns either a Video or a Photo object.  Does the Video class and the Photo class implement IEnumerator<> ??  I think not...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to add `Media` instances into a `Video` collection, and it blows up because one or more of them is a `Photo` -- you're trying to add a photo to a video collection. The error is in your client code, not in the generated enumerator.